# Query post if has two of the categories

Tags: categories

I'm banging my head here. I can't seem to figure out what's wrong with this it works although if a post has more than two categories is doesn't seem to show. What is wrong here?

```
<div class="base-column">
                        <button class="accordion">How To&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src="/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2018/11/expand-button.jpg"></button>
                        <div class="panel">
                            <?php // How To
                            $args_1 = array(
                                'post_type'     =>  'post',
                                'category__and' => array(117,123),
                            );

                            // The Query
                            $the_query_1 = new WP_Query( $args_1 ); ?>

                            <?php // The Loop
                            if ( $the_query_1->have_posts() ) {
                                while ( $the_query_1->have_posts() ) {
                                    $the_query_1->the_post(); ?>

                                    <strong>
                                        <a class="title-article" href="<?php echo the_permalink(); ?>">
                                            <?php echo get_the_title(); ?>
                                        </a>
                                    </strong><br>

                                <?php }
                                /* Restore original Post Data */
                                wp_reset_postdata();
                            } else {
                                // no posts found
                            }

                            ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit line 7.

```
'category__and' => array(117,123),
```

The category__and parameter doesn't use a string for the category IDs. Write the array like this:

```
    'category__and' => array(
        '117',
        '123'
    )
);
```